# java.lang.NumberFormatException on BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I want to calculate some stuff with Poisson.
The Problem is, it works just to a value from 183...

my Code:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.math.RoundingMode;


public class CopyOfPoisson {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double anrufe = 360;
        double minuten = 30;
        double dauer = 240;

        double agenten = 0; //m


        for(int i = 49; i<=500; i++)
        {
            agenten = i;
            double callsPerSecond = anrufe/(minuten*60);

            //u
            double trafficIntensitiy = callsPerSecond*dauer;
            //p
            double p = trafficIntensitiy / agenten;
            System.out.println("Index: "+ i + " "+ erlangC(agenten,trafficIntensitiy, p));
        }




    }

    public static BigDecimal erlangC (double m, double u, double p)
    {
        BigDecimal zaehler = berechnePoisson(m, u, false);
        BigDecimal nenner = berechnePoisson(m, u, false).add((BigDecimal.ONE.subtract(new BigDecimal(p))).multiply( berechnePoisson(m, u, true)));
        return zaehler.divide(nenner,100,RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
    }

    public static BigDecimal berechnePoisson(double m, double u, boolean va)
    {

        BigDecimal answer = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        if(!va)
        {
            BigDecimal myOwn = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(Math.exp(-u)* Math.pow(u, m)));
            answer = myOwn.divide(fakultaet2(m),100,RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
        }
        if(va)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                BigDecimal myOwn2 = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(Math.exp(-u)*Math.pow(u, i)));
                answer = answer.add(myOwn2.divide(fakultaet2(i),100,RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN));
            }
        }

        return answer;
    }


    public static BigDecimal fakultaet2 (double n)
    {
        BigDecimal fct = BigDecimal.valueOf(1);
        for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            fct = fct.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(i));
        }

        return fct;
    }

}
```

After the loop reaches 184 it gives me an Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException
at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:494)
at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:383)
at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:806)
at CopyOfPoisson.berechnePoisson(CopyOfPoisson.java:47)
at CopyOfPoisson.erlangC(CopyOfPoisson.java:36)
at CopyOfPoisson.main(CopyOfPoisson.java:26)
```

on the Line

```
BigDecimal myOwn = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(Math.exp(-u)* Math.pow(u, m)));
```

What is the problem? I want to calculate till `i <= 500`, but only calculates to `i = 183`.

Comment: So the *first* thing to do is move the `Double.toString(Math.exp(-u)* Math.pow(u, m))` call to its own statement, assigning to a local variable... then you can log that before you call `new BigDecimal`, so you can see what value is failing.

Comment: You are reaching infinity, which can't be parsed.

Comment: Oke...i see....hmmm how to fix it?

Comment: Well actually infinity can't be reached, but you get what I mean..

Comment: If you want to do math on large numbers, you have to keep everything as a BigDecimal.  You can't have double intermediate values.

Comment: how do i use the bigdecimal pow in the `Double.toString(Math.exp(-u)* Math.pow(u, m))` line?

Comment: An equivalent to `Math.exp` using `BigDecimal` would be `BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.E).pow(5).setScale(13, RoundingMode.CEILING)` (I'd store `BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.E)` in a constant). As for the multiplication between both, you can use `.multiply`.

Comment: Thanks alot. it works now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do everything using BigDecimal. For example, use BigDecimal.pow() instead of Math.pow(). Or clean up the algorithm - there is no need to use pow() or exp() when computing Poisson (I showed how in an earlier thread on Poisson today)

Comment: yes, i've seen it, but i didnt understand it, whats the last step?